# Customize the Liferay Web Service response with non-database fields

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, liferay, liferay-7, liferay-service-builder

In Liferay 7, I've customized my FooImpl.java (generated by the service builder from the Foo table) with a new field with getter/setter :

```
@ProviderType
public class FooImpl extends FooBaseImpl {

    private String toto;
    // and getter and setter

    public FooImpl() {
    }

}
```

I add this field because I want it in the Web Service response of the following method (extract from FooServiceImpl.java) :

```
@JSONWebService(value = "get-foos", method = "GET")
@AccessControlled(guestAccessEnabled=true)
public List<Foo> getFoos(){
   ...
}
```

Unfortunately, the JSON response doesn't include the custom field "toto".

Does someone has any idea how to do this ?

Comment: Is Liferay 7? It's a good question and I'm interested too..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you very much Daniele.
I've found the answer in the documentation you've provided.

Actually, it's very simple, just add the annotation @JSON(strict = false) to your model object and all custom attributes will be serialized.

```
@JSON(strict = false)
@ProviderType
public class FooImpl extends FooBaseImpl {

    private String toto;
    // and getter and setter

    public FooImpl() {
    }

}
```

Comment: pls mask the answer

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this wiki page. I have not a direct experience for this topic. Let me know if this is the right way.

https://web.liferay.com/it/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/JSON+Serialization#section-JSON+Serialization-Strict+mode